s3.listBuckets() returning "null"
This is the Error i get (Picture Link) I have a problem with my function below.
I have AdministratorAccess permissions. The function ListS3Buckets won't give me a list of all my buckets. I tried to add CORS and more permissions and its still not working. I get an error of NetworkingError: Network Failure and the Data display is data:null.
# (Note: the displayModal is a function to display data)
# Do you have suggestions?**

----------------------------------
function listS3Buckets() {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({ 
        region: currentRegion    
        });

    s3.listBuckets((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('data:', data)
            console.error('Error listing S3 buckets:', err); 
            displayModal('S3 Buckets', 'Nothing To Show...');
        } else {
            if (!data || !data.Buckets || data.Buckets.length === 0) {
                displayModal('S3 Buckets', 'No buckets found.');
            } else {
                const bucketNames = data.Buckets.map(bucket => bucket.Name);
                displayModal('S3 Buckets', bucketNames.join(', '));
            }
        }
    });
}

I tried to change the listBuckets() to listObjects(), but I don't want to be exclusive to one bucket, I want to display all of them. I also tried listAllMyBuckets() but it says that there isn't a function call that way.

Is this running in a browser?

A Network Failure error says that the code is unable to reach the Amazon S3 endpoint. The error is not related to the actual call itself, but rather the fact that it can't reach an S3 server. Can you try it on a different network (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)? Does the AWS CLI work from the same computer?

I tried running the website from various places.. From ec2 instance  public ip and my internal computer and in the office, Yes the CLI was from the same computer

You didn't answer the question, but if you're running the AWS JavaScript SDK within a browser then you cannot issue S3 API requests such as ListBuckets because S3 regional endpoints don't support CORS. You can only issue bucket-level API requests.
